# Is there an effective way to see if a string is question?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to see if a statement is a question, and even better, a question of substance? What I have is very simple but obviously extremely ineffective if statement:

```
if (string.endsWith("?")) { // }
```

A question of substance is something that is an actual question, not something stupid like `asdfasdfsafas?`

Comment: A "question of substance" determination would require artificial intelligence to analyze the sentence content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An elegant alternative, is the String.prototype.slice method.

Just by:

```js
str.slice(-1);
```

A negative start index slices the string from length+index, to length, being index -1, the last character is extracted:
You could do:

```js
string.slice(-1) == '?'
```

But as for checking if the question is of substance, I guess Machine Learning comes to play here